# How to bind other list to ItemsSource inside other ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have 2 lists in class ViewModel1 and I want binding this list to ItemsSource, but when I binding one list to first ItemsSource in second I can't binding my second list but only properies from class Movie. How binding my second list "cars" inside first ItemsSource?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel1 x:Name="hViewModel"/>
     </Grid.DataContext>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=movies}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>

                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=cars}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Label Content="{Binding Model}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>

    public class ViewModel1
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Movie> movies {get; set;} = new ObservableCollection<Movie>();
        public ObservableCollection<Car> cars { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Car>();
    }

    public class Movie
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public short Year { get; set; }
        public List<string> Cast { get; set; }
        public long HoursWatched { get; set; }
    }

    public class Car
    {
        public string Model { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: You want your `cars` list to be repeated over and over, once for each entry in `movies`?

Comment: Yes I want repeated

Comment: Change binding to use relativesource. Google it. But roughly ( no paste guarantee ) "{Binding datacontext.cars, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemControl}}"